# What exactly mean by schema? Can stored procedures and tables have different schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What exactly mean by schema? Can stored procedures and tables have different schema ?
How can i specify structure through schema?
is stored peoceduer identify object through scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema refers to database tables and how them are related to each other. Stored procedures are also part of the database, but not of the schema.

Read more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema

**UPDATED:
Stored procedures are incorrectly mentioned as not part of a database schema.**

**The answer of onedaywhen  is the right one.**

Comment: Could at least have a comment for the downvoting? Thanks in advance

Comment: Schema also means "namespace" in SQL Server 2005+ eg Data.myTable or WebGUI.GetOrders

Comment: Score is something i don't care about. I am trying to help and also improve my knowledge, that's why i ask from people downvoting, to give me some info.

Comment: You are welcome @Pearl, but thanks should be given to anyone in this post tried to help :)

Comment: Downvoted because according to the Wikipedia link you referenced yourself, a stored procedure **is** a part of the schema

Comment: You are right, I have updated my answer since I cannot remove it.

Answer (score 3):

It is subjective. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) tell us,

> In a relational database, the schema
> defines the tables, fields,
> relationships, views, indexes,
> packages, procedures, functions,
> queues, triggers, types, sequences,
> materialized views, synonyms, database
> links, directories, Java, XML schemas,
> and other elements.

..which is at odds with @niktrs's answer because he explicitly exclude's procedures from the schema.

Often I've had to enforce a database constraint for which the DBMS has no support (e.g. would require a subquery in a `CHECK` constraint) and I've resorted to removing update permissions from the base table and provding a 'helper' stored proc that must be used to update the table. In these circusmtances I could argue that the stored proc forms part of the schema.

On a practical note, if on SO I requested of a questioner, "Please post your schema" and they posted their stored proc (if it was relevant to the question) then I for one wouldn't complain ;)

Answer (score 1):

Schema in SQL Server is like "namespace" in .net. It's only been implemented correctly since SQL Server 2005 so I won't go into ancient history

Schema also refers to the table definitions, keys etc in common use. This is what you mean by "structure" I guess. This meaning is separate and different the namespace sense

Schema in the namespace sense means you can have a tables in, say, a Data schema but stored procedures in a WebGUI schema or Desktop schema. The WebGUI.GetOrders will refer to the Data.Order table.

One advantage of this is security is easier: you GRANT on the schema not on Objects